# Navigation lists, inline and with spacing

Tags: html, css, navigation, inline, spacing

i have a navigation bar and i want to be on one line it does this however there is only one space between each item, i want them to be spaced equally out, and flexible, so that when i change the window size they adjust.
this is my html

```
    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="navhead">
            <h2>Navigation</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="navlist">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Home Page.html">Home</a></li>
                <li>Chat</li>
                <li>Blog</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my css

```
.navlist li{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 10%;
}
```

please keep in mind i am in year 7 and don't use too complex words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply width of your li and if needed add padding value. But change inline to table-cell. And to apply the space between them apply border-spacing value as followings:

```
.navlist{
        border-spacing: 10px;
}


.navlist li{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000;
        list-style-type: none;
        display: table-cell;
        text-indent: 10%;
        width: 20%;
        padding: 1em;
    }
```

[Check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/clink/uZJPU/1/)

Comment: *i want them to be spaced equally out, and flexible, so that when i change the window size they adjust.* you need to use `%` and not `px` :)

Answer (score 0):

You could display the `ul` as a table, like this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    width: 90%;
    background: #222;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: #555;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Also check [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/v5NUB/).